# Cannot set property '0' of 2D array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error for the code below:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined**

```
var vehicles = [];
$.get('../poll/index.php?data=vehicles', function(data) {

    var rows = $(data).find('row').length;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        vehicles[i][0] = $(data).find('row').eq(i).find('stage').text();
        vehicles[i][1] = $(data).find('row').eq(i).find('direction').text();
        vehicles[i][2] = $(data).find('row').eq(i).find('stageName').text();
        vehicles[i][3] = $(data).find('row').eq(i).find('atco').text();
        vehicles[i][4] = $(data).find('row').eq(i).find('service').text();
        vehicles[i][5] = $(data).find('row').eq(i).find('journey').text();
        vehicles[i][6] = $(data).find('row').eq(i).find('fleet').text();
        vehicles[i][7] = $(data).find('row').eq(i).find('longitude').text();
        vehicles[i][8] = $(data).find('row').eq(i).find('latitude').text();
        vehicles[i][9] = $(data).find('row').eq(i).find('operator').text();
        vehicles[i][10] = $(data).find('row').eq(i).find('position').text();
    }

}, 'xml');
```

Comment: `vehicles[i]` is undefined. Define it first.

Comment: because the "vehicles" array is empty, would be my guess...

Comment: Side note: your code is horribly inefficient.  You should store `$(data).find('row')` and `$(data).find('row').eq(i)` in variables so that you don't perform too many unnecessary DOM queries.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I'm aware it's terrible I'm just doing this for test purposes. :)

Comment: As long as you're aware... ;-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to define each child array, e.g.

```
var vehicles = []; // parent array;
vehicles[0] = []; // first child array;
```

so you would need:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
     var vehicles[i] = [];
     ... rest of code here ...
}
```

Comment: Ahh. I feel so stupid now, it's been a long day lol. Thanks very much :) - Will accept your answer when the timer is up.

Answer (score 4):

`vehicles[i]` has no value assigned to it.

Add a line:

```
vehicles[i] = [];
```

at the top of the loop.