# Javascript multi dimensional array issue

Tags: javascript

I want to create an array like this:

```
send[1]['conversation_group_id']=1;
```

But i get an error that cannot set property conversation_group_id of undefined. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: how did you init `send`?

Comment: If you want to add a property to an Object, you need to first create that Object. Here, as the error tells you, `send[1]` is not an Object, it is not defined.

Comment: @Sirko send=[];

Comment: You've initialized the array, but not an object. `send[1]` would have to point to the second element in an array that is an object, but currently it's nothing. If you first did `send[1] = {}` and then `send[1]['conversation_group_id'] = 1` - it would work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot set property '0' of 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534323/cannot-set-property-0-of-2d-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though you have initialized send with [], which makes it an array,  send[1] will be undefined,  you will need to initialize it as an object too before you can set a property inside it. At the moment you are trying to set a property of undefined.

```js
var send = [];
console.log(send[1]);
send[1] = {};
send[1]['conversation_group_id']=1;
console.log(send[1]['conversation_group_id']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure is an array of objects. To initialize it, you can also do it this way.

```
send = [null, {conversation_group_id: 1}]
```

Nothing wrong with [@Dij's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45662889/2131286), but just though it's worth mentioning an alternative on how to *initialize* the structure you're looking for.